# Python pcl has no attribute from_array

Tags: python, point-cloud-library

I was trying to run the example on this page:
https://github.com/strawlab/python-pcl/blob/master/examples/example.py
I get the error : `AttributeError: type object 'PointCloud' has no attribute 'from_array'` on line 49. Also, i cant import few modules like `pcl.pcl_visualization` and `pcl.PointCloud_PointXYZRGB()` . Anybody knows how do i slove these issues?

Thanks

Comment: On which OS you are trying to run this ?

Comment: I am using on windows.

Comment: You installed python-pcl  package for your python version ?

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure you aren't running PyPCL by accident. This is an alternate python to PCL binding that import pcl can map to. One way to check this is to run this snippet:

```
class_names = dict([(name, cls) for name, cls in pcl.__dict__.items() if isinstance(cls, type)])
for name, cls in class_names.items():
    print(name)
```

This will give you a list of classes in the module. If there are two (PointCloud, Quaternion), you likely have PyPCL installed and should uninstall that one. The list of classes in python-pcl returned should look something like this:

```
PointCloud
PointCloud_PointXYZI
PointCloud_PointXYZRGB
PointCloud_PointXYZRGBA
Vertices
PointCloud_PointWithViewpoint
PointCloud_Normal
PointCloud_PointNormal
KdTree
RangeImages
SampleConsensusModel
SampleConsensusModelPlane
SampleConsensusModelSphere
SampleConsensusModelCylinder
SampleConsensusModelLine
SampleConsensusModelRegistration
SampleConsensusModelStick
Segmentation
Segmentation_PointXYZI
Segmentation_PointXYZRGB
Segmentation_PointXYZRGBA
SegmentationNormal
Segmentation_PointXYZI_Normal
Segmentation_PointXYZRGB_Normal
Segmentation_PointXYZRGBA_Normal
EuclideanClusterExtraction
RegionGrowing
StatisticalOutlierRemovalFilter
StatisticalOutlierRemovalFilter_PointXYZI
StatisticalOutlierRemovalFilter_PointXYZRGB
StatisticalOutlierRemovalFilter_PointXYZRGBA
VoxelGridFilter
VoxelGridFilter_PointXYZI
VoxelGridFilter_PointXYZRGB
VoxelGridFilter_PointXYZRGBA
PassThroughFilter
PassThroughFilter_PointXYZI
PassThroughFilter_PointXYZRGB
PassThroughFilter_PointXYZRGBA
ApproximateVoxelGrid
ApproximateVoxelGrid_PointXYZI
ApproximateVoxelGrid_PointXYZRGB
ApproximateVoxelGrid_PointXYZRGBA
KdTreeFLANN
KdTreeFLANN_PointXYZI
KdTreeFLANN_PointXYZRGB
KdTreeFLANN_PointXYZRGBA
OctreePointCloud
OctreePointCloud_PointXYZI
OctreePointCloud_PointXYZRGB
OctreePointCloud_PointXYZRGBA
OctreePointCloud2Buf
OctreePointCloud2Buf_PointXYZI
OctreePointCloud2Buf_PointXYZRGB
OctreePointCloud2Buf_PointXYZRGBA
OctreePointCloudSearch
OctreePointCloudSearch_PointXYZI
OctreePointCloudSearch_PointXYZRGB
OctreePointCloudSearch_PointXYZRGBA
OctreePointCloudChangeDetector
OctreePointCloudChangeDetector_PointXYZI
OctreePointCloudChangeDetector_PointXYZRGB
OctreePointCloudChangeDetector_PointXYZRGBA
CropHull
CropBox
ProjectInliers
RadiusOutlierRemoval
ConditionAnd
ConditionalRemoval
ConcaveHull
ConcaveHull_PointXYZI
ConcaveHull_PointXYZRGB
ConcaveHull_PointXYZRGBA
MovingLeastSquares
MovingLeastSquares_PointXYZRGB
MovingLeastSquares_PointXYZRGBA
GeneralizedIterativeClosestPoint
IterativeClosestPoint
IterativeClosestPointNonLinear
RandomSampleConsensus
NormalEstimation
VFHEstimation
IntegralImageNormalEstimation
MomentOfInertiaEstimation
HarrisKeypoint3D
NormalDistributionsTransform
Sequence
```

Alternatively, if you are in a virtual environment you can run `pipenv graph` to look for this issue. Or:

```
pip list
```